# Selecting a specific row from table using sql but getting expected result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table as below:

```
No  Percent date    
123 0.25    20061026    
123 0.75    20040126    
123 0.25    20061126    
123 0.25    20061226
```

I wanted o/p only one row with the lowest date as below

```
123 0.75    20040126
```

But using below query

```
select no,percent, min(date) 
from a 
group by pno,percent
```

I am getting 2 rows

```
123 0.25    20061026    
123 0.75    20040126
```

I am i doing anything wrong here?

Comment: you are asking SQL to group every distinct pair of No-Percent the table has. And for each of them, to tell you the minimum date, from all the rows with that pair of values for columns No and Percent. You are getting all the groups of No-Percent available in your table - because this is what you asked for. If you want the minimum date, regardless of no-percent groups, then you simple select MIN(field).

Comment: Also, a piece of advice: Try to avoid using `reserved keyword` when naming your columns/tables. `No`, `Percent`, `Date` are all `SQL keywords`. Please review this page for a list of reserved keywords: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238507(v=sql.80).aspx

Answer (score 3):

It is because 123 0.75 is a different group than 123 0.25, that's why you are getting two rows.

That is exactly what you asked for: "Give me the minimum Date for each (No, Perc) pair."

Comment: From @Robert_Sheahan 's answer, if you have SQLITE replace TOP 1 in the beggining to LIMIT 1 in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
select TOP 1 no,percent, [date] 
from a 
ORDER by [date]
```

EDIT: Based on the comments, maybe you want something more like this?

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Cust INT, Prct DECIMAL(6,2), Dt INT)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES (123, 0.25, 20061026), (123, 0.75, 20040126)
    , (123, 0.25, 20061126), (123, 0.25, 20061226)
    , (124, 0.27, 20061026), (124, 0.65, 20071226)
    , (124, 0.57, 20050602);
WITH cteRanked as (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Cust ORDER BY Dt) as RC FROM @T)
SELECT Cust , Prct , Dt  FROM cteRanked WHERE RC = 1
```

gives results

```
Cust    Prct    Dt
123 0.75    20040126
124 0.57    20050602
```

Comment: But i have millions records in my table, i have just pulled one record for example.

Comment: OK, I guess I don't understand what you are looking for. Are you saying you want the oldest for each customer? So if you have a million records for 100 customers you get 100 rows returned?

Comment: Are you saying you want the oldest for each customer? -- > YES    So if you have a million records for 100 customers you get 100 rows returned?  --> Yes

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try some funky query:

```
select no,percent, date 
from a
where date = (select min(date) from a)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the latest record (and percent doesn't matter) use Robert Sheahan solution !
Will show just 1 record. see ("select TOP 1")

If you want grouped by percent is correct !

Explain more detailed what you expect from query.

Edited:
"Are you saying you want the oldest for each customer? -- > YES"
So if you have a million records for 100 customers you get 100 rows returned? --> Yes

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1a15fa/11

Based on Robert solution:

```
    CREATE TABLE Table1
(
 no int,percent2 decimal(5,2),date3 date
);

    INSERT INTO Table1
 (no, percent2, date3)
 VALUES
 (123, 0.25, '20061026'),
 (123, 0.75, '20040126'),
 (124, 0.45, '20060726'),
 (124, 0.55, '20031126'),
 (125, 0.65, '20040526'),
 (125, 0.35, '20060926'),
 (126, 0.25, '20061226');


 WITH cteRanked as (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY no ORDER BY date3) as RC FROM Table1)
 SELECT no, percent2, date3 FROM cteRanked WHERE RC = 1
```

result:

```
 NO     PERCENT2    DATE3
 123    0.75    2004-01-26
 124    0.55    2003-11-26
 125    0.65    2004-05-26
 126    0.25    2006-12-26
```

the customer with the oldest date !

see: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1a15fa/11

Comment: I want a row (all 3 columns - no, percent, date) with the lowest date. [ and my table there are millions of such records, so i want to write generic query where i should get only one records with above condition]

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping by No. and Percent so the DB would throw one line for each different combination of No. and Percent (That is why you get two rows). For each group it will calculate the minimum date, so you are getting the minimum date for both groups: (123, 0.25) and (123, 0.75)

You might solve this problem by ordering in increasing order and then using the TOP clause to limit just to the first row (Check the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7aebc/4/0)):

```
SELECT TOP 1 number, perc, date
FROM sof 
ORDER by date
```

An alternative would be to use a subquery to return the minimum date and then filter using it in the WHERE clause (Check the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7aebc/6/0)):

```
SELECT
   number, perc, date 
FROM 
   sof, (
       SELECT MIN(date) min_date
       FROM sof
   ) md
WHERE sof.date = md.min_date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
select a.*
from table1 a
inner join (select no,min(date) mindate from table1 group by no) b
    on a.no=b.no and a.date=b.mindate
```